# Why do Examples of the Repository Pattern never deal with Database Connection Exceptions?

Tags: architecture, exception, repository-pattern

I've read a lot of tutorials and seen a lot of code samples regarding implementations of the `Repository` pattern. In pretty much every case, exceptions that would result from attempting to hit the database when the database is unavailable is not addressed. This seems strange considering that this is a very realistic scenario if the DB is somewhere on a network.

So what is the best practice for handling these exceptions?

- Wrap each of those hundred calls in a try/catch, where each one might have
  the same *n* catch blocks? That's a lot of duplication, messy, error-prone, etc.
- Let the exceptions bubble up to the app level an catch them as
  unhandled exceptions? This makes sense if the exception is thrown on the UI thread, but otherwise, the handling of an unhandled AppDomain exception results in the app shutting down.
- Use a framework such as Enterprise Library's Exception
  Handling Application Block?

Comment: Many errors can't be retried at the repository level. For example deadlocks, timeouts, network errors must be retried at the transaction level which can span multiple repo operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly think that it isn't addressed because of the ongoing (and emotional) debate about what to do with exceptions.  There is a constant back and forth over whether exceptions should be handled locally (where there is a greater chance of understanding them and doing something intelligent, like retrying) or handled at the UI layer (where 99.9% of exceptions eventually bubble up to).

Personally, I find it most elegant to do the try/catch inside the Repository layer, to catch the database-specific exceptions, and throw a new exception of my own making.  That gives me a place to put retry logic.  I can also then make the decision about whether that DAOException is a checked or a runtime exception.

This allows the user interface to deal with a known exception, and it helps me to isolate my higher-level layers from any provider-specific errors.  For example, if I was migrating my data store to a No-SQL database like Mongo or Cassandra, I could still throw the same exceptions, and maintain their semantic meaning, without changing all the calling code.

Comment: So every repository method would have pretty much the same try/catch structure? In my application (entity framework), right or wrong, each time I access the database I have a separate `catch` for `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException` and `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException`. Seems like there would be a lot of updating to do if I found a 3rd exception type to handle...

Comment: Yes, but the point is that you would have to handle it only when you are changing the data layer.  And you would *only* have to change it in the data layer.  As opposed to letting it propagate up, and having to handle it at all layers.  Keep the database responsibilities in the DAO layer.

Comment: But what about different UI's handling the error on different ways (for example a WPF app popping up a message box but a console app writing to the console, and so on)?

Comment: That's why I throw my own exception.  So i can handle a known exception type.

Answer (score 1):

First, because [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). A class only handle one and only one responsibility. At least in a method it is.

Second, it depends on what you need to do with the failure. Will you only **show the error message** to user? **Handle it at application-level** since data-level and business-level do not know what UI is there.

If you have a logic, for example: if the database cannot be accessed, use the offline cache, handle it using [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or similar, ex:

```
public class OnlineUserRepository : IUserRepository{
    public User Get(){ /* get the user from online source */ }
}

public class OfflineUserRepository : IUserRepository{
    public User Get(){ /* get the user from offline source */ }
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository{
    public UserRepository(IUserRepository onlineRepo, IUserRepository offlineRepo){
        //parameter assignment
    }
    IUserRepository onlineRepo;
    IUserRepository offlineRepo;
    public User Get(){
        try{
            onlineRepo.Get();
        }
        catch{
            return offlineRepo.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

Why we need to handle it that way? Again, because [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).